# C++ 2D array blank output

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to output a 2D array with a border around it but for some odd reason I am not getting any output, just a blank space. I am pretty sure the problem is in the if statement but im not sure whats wrong.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "windows.h"
using namespace std;

//prototypes
void DisplayMap();
void SetBorder();

//global vars
const int H = 70;
const int W = 40;
char Map[H][W];

int main()
{
    //system("cls");
    DisplayMap();
    SetBorder();

    return 0;
}

void SetBorder(){
for(int i = 0; i < H; i++ ){
    for(int j = 0; j < W; j++){
        if(i == 0 || i == 69 || j == 0 || j == 39 ){ Map[i][j] = 'x';}
            // else Map[i][j] = ' ';
        }
    }
}


void DisplayMap(){
for(int i = 0; i < H; i++ ){
    for(int j = 0; j < W; j++){
            cout << Map[i][j];
        }
            cout << "\n";
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fill the `Map` first and then to display it:

```
int main()
{
    //system("cls");
    SetBorder();
    DisplayMap();


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SetBorder();
DisplayMap();
```

Swap the function calls. You want to set the border characters first, *then* display the map.